# How FilterDispatcher reads the Struts.xml file

Tags: struts2

For Struts2 , we simply add this line inside web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But could anybody please tell me , how it will know the path of struts.xml file ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts2 looks for the struts.xml file at the root of the classpath. You can override the location using the `config` init param, if needed.

The actual configuration is set up by the `Dispatcher` class, irrespective of whether you use the older `FilterDispatcher` or the newer `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`.

Comment: can you also include the web.xml with setting the config init param. I added the struts.xml file in the default class path but getting 404 error while accessing the pages.